# Can I back a Sencha Touch Card Layout with a Store?

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a view (`Panel`) that is a card layout. I have a `Store` of, say, `n` items. I want to create a stack of `n` cards, each of which is backed by an item in the `Store`. How can I do this without manually adding `n` cards in a `for` loop, iterating through the items in the `Store`?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to just use a `for` loop?

Comment: I would need to maintain a separate list when I already have my `Store` that contains everything I need. I want to be able to filter the store in order to only have certain cards on the stack. It would seem more elegant and idiomatic to just use a `Store`.

Comment: It's gonna be a little bit of work to do that. You will need to create a new custom component which handles it all for you. Thankfully the `Ext.data.Store` component in ST 2.x has great events, so it should just be a matter of listening to those events, and replacing existing components when necessary. It will be difficult to optimize though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate list to contain all your cards, you CANNOT connect panel's list of cards with a store (at least in current version of Sencha Touch).

You cannot avoid adding manually, but you can avoid for loops:

```
Ext.regModel('someModel', { 
    fields: [
        {name: 'title', type: 'string' },
        {name: 'info', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

var someStore = new Ext.data.Store({ 

    model: "someModel",
    listeners:{
        add:function(store, list, index){
            //here list is list of records you added
            var item = list[0];
            panelinstance.insert(index, {...whatever component...panel,list,carousal whatever});
        }
    } 
});
```

Careful about the caller: Add one item at a time to your store(this might sound ridiculous), but I think it is the only way to make your panel "CONNECT" to a store.